Set beamer header background color
I'm using the Madrid theme for beamer and I want to put my logo inside the header. Is there a way to change the header background color? I've tried to do as following, but nothing changed.
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{RGB}{25,25,89}
\setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=DarkBlue}
\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\small}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \vspace{-0.5mm}\hspace{-0.5mm}\includegraphics[width=1cm]{Logo.png}\vspace{-0.3mm}
}

The background just went... white.


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You can use a beamercolorbox around your logo:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\definecolor{DarkBlue}{RGB}{25,25,89}
\setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=DarkBlue}
\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\small}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}


